# Proving an inequality which is hard

Tags: inequality

show that:

$\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{6}\cdots \frac{99}{100}<1/10$

How would you do this, is from a book i can't recall the name of. (no brute evaluation is allowed of course)

Comment: So we have ${99!\over 2^{49}49!2^{50}50!}$ which can also be written $\binom {99}{49}\frac 1{2^{99}}$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Use $n^2>(n-1)(n+1)$ to write
$$LHS^2<\frac{1.1.3.3.5.5\cdots99.99}{1.3.3.5.5.7\cdots99.101}$$